# What is the best option to store a step functions' state

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-step-functions

I have a step function which needs a rather large state (memory passed between its states) in order to do its job. This state was larger than the memory that can be passed by the step function engine. Searching online, one solution to this was using S3 buckets as the alternative. Now, I've reached another limitation. S3 is eventually consistent and as a result, I'm losing data from time to time. By that I mean the data read from the bucket is not the latest state.

My question is, does anyone know a better option/solution to keep the state for a step function?

Answer (score 1):

Use a new S3 key every time you modify the state information, then there's no risk of stale data caused by S3's consistency model.